# Can I return a different type other than agtype on age return query

Tags: apache-age

Recently I came across a problem where I want to convert `agtype` to `json` for the node `v` as given in the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$ MATCH (u)-[]-(v) RETURN id(u), v $$) as (id agtype, v agtype);
```

I want a `json` value to be returned instead of `agtype` for the column `v`.
Can you help me in running something like:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph', $$ MATCH (u)-[]-(v) RETURN id(u), v $$) as (id agtype, v json);
```

Answer (score 1):

AGE uses a custom data type called **agtype**, which is the only data type returned by AGE. further read [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/types.html)

At this point age cannot cast type agtype to json for any column.

But this feature can be included, you can request this feature in the apache-age repository [here](https://github.com/apache/age/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Currently AGE itself doesn't support this feature, however there is at least 1 possible work around that I could think of.

Consider the following query:

```
WITH graph_customers AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cypher('customers',
    $$
        MATCH (p:person)
        RETURN properties(p)
    $$
    ) as (p agtype)
)
```

This creates a CTE (common table expression) for us that returns all the properties of nodes with the label `person`. We store it under the name of `graph_customers`.

We can't directly cast agtype to JSON, so first we cast our property map to VARCHAR using `CAST(p as VARCHAR)`. Then we CAST this VARCHAR to JSON. Putting the query together, it would look like this:

```
    WITH graph_customers AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cypher('customers',
    $$
        MATCH (p:person)
        RETURN properties(p)
    $$
    ) as (p agtype)
)
SELECT CAST(CAST(p as VARCHAR) as JSON) 
FROM graph_customers;
                      p                       
----------------------------------------------
 {"last_name": "Smith", "first_name": "Adam"}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

AGE allows multiple implicit and explicit casting options such as agtype to int2, int4, int8, float etc but right now casting agtype to json or jsonb is not supported. However, there is a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/AGEDB-INC/postgraph/issues/125) that could be worked on for supporting agtype -> jsonb typecasting

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only data type in age is *agtype*. We can do this by casting this agtype into VARCHAR and then the VARCHAR into json. But for now, directly it is not possible